# Compare the nulls across 3 columns and match with column that has the value in EXCEL SpreadSheets

Tags: excel, vba

Lets assume I have 4 columns:

Sub1, Sub2, Sub3, and a result column as dropdown list in ADHOC FORM sheet.

In Requirement ID sheet I have Sub1,Sub2,Sub3 names as the column names and respective result in the respective column.

Now, I need to Match the respective sub3 from the AdhoCForm sheet in the Requirement ID sheet:

- IF Sub3 has a value. It need to match it in the Requirement ID sheet and get the respective data in the columns.
- If Sub3 is null, it should select from Sub2.
- If Sub2 is null, It should select from sub1.

For now, I am using

```
=INDEX(RequirementId!$A$2:$WYZ$10000,0,MATCH(AdhocForm!Q17,RequirementId!$A$1:WZS$1,0))
```

[image: Requirement ID]

Requirement ID

[image: AdhocForm]

Adhoc Form

Please help.

Comment: Please revise the edited version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming

- your columns `Sub1, Sub2 and Sub3` are `A, B, C` in sheet `AdhocForm`
- The rows to search in `RequirementId` are rows 1 and 2

Type this formula somewhere in row 2 of `AdhocForm` then copy/paste down in the column

```
=INDEX(RequirementId!$2:$2, MATCH(IF(ISBLANK(C2), IF(ISBLANK(B2), A2, B2), C2),
   RequirementId!$1:$1))
```

Comment: =INDEX(RequirementId!$A$2:$WYZ$10000,MATCH(IF(ISBLANK(AdhocForm!S17), IF(ISBLANK(AdhocForm!R17),AdhocForm!Q17,AdhocForm!R17),AdhocForm!S17),RequirementId!$A$1:WZP$1,0))

Comment: it didn't went through ASH!

Comment: @GeethamruthSeshuNemalipuri   `=INDEX(RequirementId!$2:$2,MATCH(IF(ISBLANK(AdhocF‌​orm!S17), IF(ISBLANK(AdhocF‌​orm!R17),AdhocF‌​orm!Q17,AdhocF‌​orm!R17),AdhocF‌​orm!S17),RequirementId!$1:$1,0))`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to did that and i have changed it.

Comment: Worked perfect! :D

Answer (score 0):

Index/Match is a good approach, and if your SubFeature columns are limited to 3, you can hard-code it using IFERROR:

`=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(G5,E:E,0)),INDEX(D:D,MATCH(G5,D:D,0))),INDEX(C:C,MATCH(G5,C:C,0)))`

This lookup works across columns, you could switch it to operate on rows.

[image: lookup proof]